# displaying something on screen for 5 seconds and then not displaying it any more

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button my screen and on click of that and after a second  I want to show something on my screen for five seconds and then no more .I understand that it requires setTimeout and clearTimeinterval but I couldn't get this working .
Here is the code .

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      display: false
    };
  }
  handler = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ display: true });
    }, 1000);
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {// this where I couldn't get things done 
    clear
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.display);
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>This is heading </h4>
        <button onClick={this.handler}>CLICK</button>
        {this.state.display === true ? "lalala" : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use another function which sets display to false when setTimeout is triggered in handler function. So here hideShowing function changes display to false with setTimeout. This should resolve your issue. Make sure you clear them in componentWillUnMount

```
  handler = () => {
     this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({ display: true });
         this.hideShowing();
      }, 1000);
  };

  hideShowing = () => {
   this.timer1=  setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({
             display: false
         });
     }, 1000);
 }

 componentWillUnMount(){
     clearTimeout(this.timer);
     clearTimeout(this.timer1);
 }
```

Comment: Question, is it strictly necessary to clear them, barring the case where user repeats the clicks on the button? Once they expire (if we'd have not stored a reference on the object) the should be garbage collected, leaving no leakage, no? Also I'd do the clearing process within the `handler`, since if the user keeps clicking the button, it will trigger/override the initial timers, for that other case where we do want to prevent the user multiclicks